# Problemas a conectar formulario a cluster MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, docker, cluster

Tengo un cluster de bases de datos mysql las cuales se encuentran cada una en contenedor docker bajo la misma red, al cluster se accede a través de un balanceador de carga (haproxy) el cual redirige las peticiones a un nodo u otro, eso aparentemente funciona de forma correcta, el problema viene cuando intento crear formulario web usando html, css y php, el codigo del formulario es el siguiente

Cuando pulso el botón de submit la pagina no reacciona, ni realiza la consulta ni muestra ningún mensaje de error, por lo que no se lo que esta ocurriendo, no se si el problema esta en el código, en el clúster o en el balanceador

E probado a cambiar el nombre de la tabla, a acceder al esquema.nombredetabla, todo esto en la variable $conexion y por si alguno lo piensa, si se puede acceder al clúster a través de haproxy, lo he comprobado con mysql_workbench y se conecta a todos los nodos de forma correcta, aunque hay veces que si hago por ejemplo la consulta SELECT * FROM usuarios.data; o SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'usuarios';

Algunas veces me dice que no encuentra resultados y otras me los muestra sin problemas.

[image: código backend, los datos de acceso mysqli_connect están cambiados por motivos obvios)]

[image: código frontend]

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y coloca el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.